# Tying new tzitzis during the Nine Days

Tags: clothing, tzitzis, nine-days

Are you permitted to tie new tzitzis on an old beged during the Nine Days? Would it make a difference if your current tzitzis weren't passul, but just looked ratty?

Additionally, what about buying a new tallis katan altogether?

Comment: Why do you think this might be problematic?

Comment: @DoubleAA - You cannot purchase new clothes during the Nine Days; especially those in which you say Shehechiyanu on. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84391/do-you-say-shechiyanu-on-a-used-tallis-you-tied-new-tzitzis-onto And, I mentioned the tzitzis don't necessarily need to be replaced, they are just ratty. So you're not even doing it out of necessity to fulfill a mitzvah, just good looks.

Comment: So doesn't this question just boil down to that one? And remember to include motivation in the question when asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inferring from Ram"a on [O.C. 551:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=48) that buying a new tallit kattan would be permitted during the 9 days as this is for the purpose of a mitzvah. (See Ram"a about 8 lines down, who says ... אם לא לצורך מצוה.)

I would further infer that tying tzizit on an old *begged* should be less of a concern. Not only is this לצורך מצוה, but if you were tying it onto a non-freshly laundered garment, I really couldn't see a problem. However, because of לצורך מצוה, I think it would be fine even if you tied it onto a just laundered garment.