# Do you say Shechiyanu on a used tallis you tied new tzitzis onto?

Tags: blessing, tzitzis, shehecheyanu

If you tied new tzitzis on an old beged, do you recite Shehechiyanu on the tallis?

Comment: FWIW when I put new tzitzis on my grandfather's tallis, which I use as my weekday tallis, I didn't say shehechiyanu.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Did a rabbi instruct you not to say Shehechiyanu on it or did you just decide based on your judgment? FWIW I have never said it when I've tied new tzitzis either, but...

Comment: I didn't because it wasn't a new beged, which is a machloket for the berachah IIRC. In any case, saying shehechiyanu could be a safek deoraita (lechumra, one shouldn't make a berachah unless sure that it's appropriate).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you don't, you only make shechiyanu on a new Tallit (when you put on the tzitzit), but never on an old one. See Mishna Berura OC 22 sif katan 2,

> אם עשה ציצית בבגד שהיה לו מכבר אף שלא היה בו ציצית מעולם אין צריך לברך
>    שהחיינו
>
> If one makes (attaches) tzitzis on a garment that he already had, even
>   if tzitzis had never been attached to it, one does not have to bless
>   *shehecheyanu*